# get image path from html using php

Tags: php, image

```
 <img src="/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" data-ytimg="1" alt="Selected Scenes" width="48" height="48" data-thumb="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Uv6Rd75Qp0o/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/pP6iGol5oVY/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" onload=";window.__ytRIL &amp;&amp; __ytRIL(this)" >
```

i want to take the image path inside the data-thumb using php. i tried this

```
$img = $d->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$imgOfText = $img->getAttribute('data-thumb');
echo $imgOfText;
```

but this is not working.please suggest correct method

Comment: $img = $d->getElementsByTagName('img'); please post `var_dump($img);`

Comment: object(DOMNodeList)#30 (1) { ["length"]=> int(22) }

Answer (score 0):

Once I need the same, I used following code, Please modify as per need, this will give you just an idea n hope this will help

```
$html = '<img src="/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" data-ytimg="1" alt="Selected Scenes" width="48" height="48" data-thumb="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Uv6Rd75Qp0o/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/pP6iGol5oVY/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"  >'
    . '<img src="/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" data-ytimg="1" alt="Selected Scenes" width="48" height="48" data-thumb="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Uv6Rd75Qp0o/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/pP6iGol5oVY/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"  >';


$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$items2 = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');

            if ($items2->length) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i++) {
                    $sliderImages[$i]['src'] = $items2->item($i)->getAttribute('src');  //get src
                    $sliderImages[$i]['thumb'] = $items2->item($i)->getAttribute('data-thumb'); //get data-thumb attrivute
                }
            }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($sliderImages);
```